# Jumping a ladder

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, estimation

Is it possible for a person to physically jump a ladder off the ground while standing on the ladder? The ladder is leaning at 10 degrees and contacting a rough surface at 20 feet and the individual wanting to jump the ladder to move it to another location a foot away stands on the ladder at 18 ft and weighs 200 lbs. The ladder weighs 75 lbs.

Comment: I was accused of doing this very thing.I had attached a rope to the ladder to secure it to a tree limb and when I untied the rope the ladder collapsed (extension ladder) The individual claimed that I was trying to jump the ladder to move it.I replied the base of the ladder had been moved while I was away and once I untied the rope securing the ladder it collapsed.He claims I had physically jumped the ladder leading to its collapse.I believe he is a liar but need proof to dispute his claim .It would seem to me to be an impossible feat to accomplish

Comment: I guess the answer is yes, since once you're on the ladder and jump, you want to hold the ladder with your hands and so as soon as your feet leave the ladder, you're able to lift the ladder up with you. Of course, this is hypothetical and not to be tried unless you know what you're doing :p

Comment: Wouldn't my feet leaving the ladder begin my fall downward and make it impossible to promote upward lift ?

Comment: Once you're up and your speed hasn't become zero, you would lift the ladder with you hands. The same thing you do with a skateboard when performing an ollie (instead of the hands you use your legs)

Comment: You may want to write an answer instead of using the comments section @OussamaBoussif

Comment: I have done it,it is  possible

Comment: You have physically jumped a 2 piece extension ladder while standing on a rung 18 ft in the air and leaning against a tree limb at 10 degrees that would cause friction ?Wow,how high did you jump it?. Did the ladder collapse,you must be super strong to do that as well considering you are going to have to lift your weight,the weight of the ladder as well as overcome friction and gravity

Comment: I do not know about your specific details, what I am saying is that I have moved it while roofing, most likely did not move more than a couple of  inches on each jump, and no idea how much it raised each time. Good look in your lawsuit, you are gonna need it! I do not think it was a two piece, in that case it would likely collapse

Comment: Related to [Internal forces in an isolated system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277978)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, it is possible, but practically very difficult to do for any more than a couple of centimetres, even with a light ladder.

Think of falling off the ladder, while on your way down, you could still reach out and apply an upward force on the ladder, accelerating yourself down faster.

This is the same as jumping up off the ladder, and using the time you're in the air to apply upward force. This will bring you down and into contact with the ladder quicker than if you didn't apply the upward force. Thus the limited practicality.

Comment: I guess I'm not making it clear enough.He stated I physically jumped the ladder while I was standing on it,not jumping off of it.He states in a legal document that he saw me standing on the ladder rungs and using my body motion to physically jump the ladder off the ground to another position .I know that's false but need a scientific principal to dispel it.It is a legal matter and was hoping someone who collectively is smarter than I and understands physics could tell me why it isn't possible for me to do.Guess I'll look elsewhere.I did have a professor tell me it was impossible,but need proof

Comment: This answer describes exactly what I said in the comments while I clearly stated that the feet jump off the ladder and then you lift it @user156011

Comment: ok,Then how about this,if feet never left the ladder,so now is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in principle you can jump a ladder, as this video demonstrates: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuUuiLxVBkU

Comment: That's not an extension ladder ,nor is it 20 ft in the air and leaning into a tree limb at a 10 degree angle.That 4 sticks nailed together,lol

Comment: True, but the physics principles are exactly the same. There is no physics principle that makes your specific example impossible.